# Optimising MySQL query with 4 JOINS and

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to optimize MySQL query as much as possible because currently database is crashing. We have 5 tables:

- order - contains about 200 000 records
- language - contains 2-5
- records order_product - contains over 200 000 records
- product - contains less than a 100 records
- newsletter - contains over 50 000 records

**Things starts going wrong when we try to join newsletter table on email...**

Here are create tables of each:

```
CREATE TABLE `order` (
 `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `order_id_copy` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `invoice_no` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `invoice_prefix` varchar(26) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `store_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `store_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `customer_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `firstname` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `lastname` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(96) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `telephone` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `fax` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `payment_firstname` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `payment_lastname` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `payment_company` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `payment_company_id` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `payment_tax_id` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `payment_address_1` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `payment_address_2` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `payment_city` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `payment_postcode` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `payment_country` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `payment_country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `payment_zone` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `payment_zone_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `payment_address_format` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `payment_method` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `payment_code` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `shipping_firstname` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `shipping_lastname` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `shipping_company` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `shipping_address_1` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `shipping_address_2` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `shipping_city` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `shipping_postcode` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `shipping_country` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `shipping_country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `shipping_zone` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `shipping_zone_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `shipping_address_format` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `shipping_method` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `shipping_code` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `comment` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `total` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
 `order_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `affiliate_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `commission` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL,
 `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `currency_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `currency_code` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `currency_value` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1.00000000',
 `ip` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `forwarded_ip` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `user_agent` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `accept_language` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
 `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL,
 `newsletter` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`),
 KEY `date_added` (`date_added`),
 KEY `date_modified` (`date_modified`),
 KEY `date_added_2` (`date_added`),
 KEY `store_id` (`store_id`),
 KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`),
 KEY `customer_group_id` (`customer_group_id`),
 KEY `payment_company_id` (`payment_company_id`),
 KEY `payment_tax_id` (`payment_tax_id`),
 KEY `payment_country_id` (`payment_country_id`),
 KEY `payment_zone_id` (`payment_zone_id`),
 KEY `shipping_country_id` (`shipping_country_id`),
 KEY `shipping_zone_id` (`shipping_zone_id`),
 KEY `order_status_id` (`order_status_id`),
 KEY `affiliate_id` (`affiliate_id`),
 KEY `language_id` (`language_id`),
 KEY `currency_id` (`currency_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=421544 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin

CREATE TABLE `language` (
 `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `code` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
 `locale` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `image` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 `directory` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `filename` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 `sort_order` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`language_id`),
 KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `order_product` (
 `order_product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `model` varchar(24) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `quantity` int(4) NOT NULL,
 `price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
 `total` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
 `tax` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
 `discount` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL,
 `discount_tax` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL,
 `reward` int(8) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`order_product_id`),
 KEY `order_id` (`order_id`),
 KEY `product_id` (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1243823 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin

CREATE TABLE `product` (
 `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `model` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 `sku` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 `upc` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
 `ean` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
 `jan` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
 `isbn` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
 `mpn` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 `location` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
 `quantity` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `stock_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `manufacturer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `shipping` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
 `points` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `tax_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `date_available` date NOT NULL,
 `weight` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
 `weight_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `length` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
 `width` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
 `height` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
 `length_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `subtract` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `minimum` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `sort_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `date_added` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `viewed` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
 KEY `model` (`model`),
 KEY `stock_status_id` (`stock_status_id`),
 KEY `manufacturer_id` (`manufacturer_id`),
 KEY `tax_class_id` (`tax_class_id`),
 KEY `weight_class_id` (`weight_class_id`),
 KEY `length_class_id` (`length_class_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=135 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `newsletter` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `email` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
 `agreed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Here's the SQL:

```
SELECT o.order_id,
       o.firstname,
       o.lastname,
       o.email,
       o.telephone,
       LOWER(l.code) AS language_code,
       o.currency_code,
       o.total,
       o.date_added,
       o.order_status_id,
       op.product_id,
       p.sku,
       op.price,
       op.model,
       op.name,
       op.tax,
       nl.agreed
FROM `order` o
JOIN LANGUAGE l ON l.language_id = o.language_id
LEFT JOIN order_product op ON op.order_id = o.order_id
LEFT JOIN product p ON p.product_id = op.product_id
LEFT JOIN newsletter nl ON nl.email = o.email
WHERE o.order_status_id IN(3,
                           5)
  AND o.order_id > '0'
ORDER BY o.order_id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Can't figure out how else can we optimize SQL, even when we do only LIMIT 1.

Comment: You don't have four left joins in that query, there are only three...

Comment: I'm sorry but there are 4 JOINS.

Comment: Note: `AND o.order_id > '0'` :: you are comparing an int to a string literal here. (and maybe at different places,too. TL;DR)

Comment: Are emails unique in `newsletter`?

Comment: No they are not

Comment: Could you show the result of `explain select...` of your query ? Also the index works better when they are of same size and datatype here in your case on `order` its email varchar(96) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,` and on `newsletter` its `email varchar(254) NOT NULL,`  and they need both to be same type and len and perhaps the collate and finally index on both.

Comment: so which `agreed` are you selecting? or do you want to return a Cartesian?

Answer (score 0):

I personally try to avoid joins on varchars. That said, if you cannot improve the design, you might consider adding indexes on your email columns, that will at least improve the search performance.

Hope that helps

Comment: We tried indexes and that didn't help. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: On both tables?

Comment: Yes, putting indexes on email columns on both tables gave no result.

Answer (score 0):

If the query is really long - I'd try to add index(order_id, order_status_id) + maybe rewrite ORDER BY to

> ORDER BY o.order_id, order_status_id

In such case the Query should finish 'instantly'.

If still no luck - you can try to select single order first then join the rest of tables to  that row.

(Ah, and since you are using myisam - make sure that other queries don't affect execution time, e.g. benchmark on idle server)

Comment: That did not help. The thing is that newsletters JOIN on varchar is using all resources.

Comment: I bet it just doesn't use new index for some reasons. Did you check EXPLAIN? In any case you can select one row from order in subquery, only then JOIN all other tables - that way it cannot consume any resourses at all